# Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070057

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, visual-studio-code

I have been stuck here for quite a while.

- I know this is pretty basic, but plss help me out on this one.
- I am familiar with Visual Studio for quite some time. So decided to give VS Code a shot.

I wanted to compile and run a simple 'Hello World' program in C#.[ref. Brackeys(Youtube)]

I have followed all the steps, but when I type in the cmd "**dotnet run**"

```
                           Failed to create CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80070057
```

This is what happens.

Are there any steps missing? Or some installation error, or I am missing some steps?

I am running this on :

- Windows 10 [x64]
- dotnet-sdk-3.1.402-win-x64
- VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.49.2

[[image: Screenshot of the window1]

Comment: Congratulations on surfacing a bug in CoreCLR!

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291362/1783163).

Answer (score 6):

I think you've found a bug in the .NET SDK. It doesn't appear to like the folder name for the project being `;)`.

If I have it in `#Code` it runs fine. If I put it in `#Code\;)` then it fails with the same error.

[image]

[image]

I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/13954

Answer (score 2):

The offending character is actually the `;` (semicolon) character in your path. I had a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68051547/asp-net-core-or-asp-net-core-mvc-solution-fails-to-run-iis-express-throws-http), and once I renamed the path, my solution ran fine. Also note that having the `^` character (caret) can cause different issues in Visual Studio. Beyond those two, the path can contain any special character other than `\/:*?"<>|` which are prohibited by Windows.

Comment: Cool! and unexpectedly. In russian, short name of this situation is 'SSZB'... approximately "evil Pinocchio for himself"

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue with your dotnet sdk version. Go to program files-dotnet-sdk. If you have multiple versions delete the unwanted version. Cross check in command prompt for dotnet version. If you are not getting your required version. Click on the sdk in your download and click repair.